# PostgreSQL 9.3 and peer authentication

Tags: postgresql

This seems stupid simple but it's not working.

My `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# type  database        user         address          type
local   all             postgres                      peer  # postgres user
local   all             fred                          peer  # fred should be able to get in w/o password
host    all             all          127.0.0.1/32     peer  # ipv6 local connections
host    all             all          ::1/128          peer  # ipv4 local
host    all             all          0.0.0.0/0        md5   # authenticated from any host
```

Now, good old `fred` can connect find when just doing `psql freddb`, but when `fred` tries `psql -h localhost freddb` it prompts for a password, which I feel like it shouldn't by virtue of the third line in `pg_hba`. What gives, friends? Help old `fred` out here.

Comment: TCP/IP connections are not [local](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER).

Comment: You can't use `peer` for `host` connections, it's unix-socket only. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER

Answer (score 1):

Peer authentication is supported on local sockets only. When you try to restart postgres with the given configuration it will fail with a fatal error.